# How to remove images by ajax in Jquery.Filer plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm using great plugin: https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer

But I cant find how to implement ajax images removing.
Plugin has onRemove function but I cant figure out how to pass any image identifier to it.
Plugin has also Filer Variables but they doesnt work in this function:

```
onRemove: function(){ var info = '{{fi-name}}'; alert(info); },
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the answear on Github [issue](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer/issues/17).

Comment: You posted a link that is now dead. Try not to post links as answers